# Sketch - How to batch point symbol instances referencing symbols inside a document to an external library file

Tags: sketch-app, batch-processing

I'm excited about the new [library symbols functionality in Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/libraries/library-symbols). However, the transition seems it is going to be onerous from the old way with the ~50 symbols I currently have been keeping inside a document with a set of screens.

The file I have with a set of screens and also some local symbols that the screens reference is called NI-539.sketch. I duplicated it and deleted all the non-symbol pages and saved this as a separate file called Library - Qual.sketch. Then I added Library - Qual.sketch as an external library file from the preferences as in https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/libraries/adding-libraries . Now NI-539.sketch is still referring to its local symbols. I'd like to convert all symbol references to now refer to the symbols in the external Library - Qual.sketch with the same symbol name so that I can refer to this central set of symbols from many screen documents. Is this possible to do in a batch? The only thing I've been able to figure out how to do seems to require changing symbol references one by one.

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins that allow you to do this:

[Library Symbol Replacer](https://sketchapphub.com/resource/library-symbol-replacer/)

This plugin allows you to easily replace symbols in the current document with symbols from a library document

[Symbol Swapper Plugin](https://github.com/sonburn/symbol-swapper)

Lets you swap selected symbols or all symbols in a file for symbols in the library of your choice

[Automate Sketch](https://github.com/Ashung/Automate-Sketch/blob/master/readme.md)

Has several functions for managing links between symbols and libraries.